# Sitecore RAZL The connector test failed. The reason is 'OldVersion' Error

Tags: razl

When trying to create a connection to a **Sitecore 8.2** CM Server using the **RAZL** ([v 4.0.9](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/-/media/Razl/Files/Razl%20V409.zip) released on May 28, 2019 ) sync tool, I get the following error that I've never seen before.

> The connector test failed. The reason is 'OldVersion'

Here's the entire screenshot.

[image]
I am confident that the **Server URL** and **Access GUID** values are both correct (i.e. no fat-fingering or typing error) as I copy-paste-ed them from our private repository wherein we store all this information securely.

The same version of RAZL was working previously on my VM. After the VM crashed a last week, I re-installed the same version of RAZL that I used before.

Has anyone encountered this error before? How did you resolve it?

Comment: seems you are using Package connection could you please try Direct connection. Below is the link for documentation.

https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/razl/connections.html